# Rails and active_storage: Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`: (RuntimeError) Missing service adapter for "S3"

Tags: rails-activestorage

I see this error in my console when all the configuration is right

```
Cannot load `Rails.config.active_storage.service`: (RuntimeError) Missing service adapter for "S3"
```

Answer (score 19):

It is not clear in the documentation, I have to add the gem `aws-sdk-s3` to my Gemfile

```
gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false
```

Comment: This is clearly documented here: 
https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#s3-service-amazon-s3-and-s3-compatible-apis

Comment: @Abel's tip was perfect for me, I needed to update the gem.